# xmodmap hanging the system for 20 secs and not sticking

Tags: linux-mint, x11, xmodmap

I edited the keyboard map using xmodmap as per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap, and I have two problems: executing `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` completely hangs the system for 15-25secs, which seems a bit odd considereing I'm just remapping the keyboard, and the changes don't stick on logoff, and not even on suspend.

It's a pain in the ass for my boot time to be increased by 20 secs or more, plus having to run it everytime I wake up from suspend. Is this normal (I don't really think so?) and is there anything I can do, perhaps an alternative way to remap the keyboard?

Linux Mint 15 x64 Cinnamon

Comment: This is not normal. Can you identify a specific line in your `.Xmodmap` that causes this delay?

Comment: I suppose I could do some testing, but I've only switched around the Home/End/PgUp/PgDwn keys, so I don't think the problem resides there.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem with the xmodmap command to freeze the system for ~20 seconds. It appeared that I had the whole keymap in my `.Xmodmap` file, which forced xmodmap to remap every row in the config file.

This is how I solved that:

Before initiating custom xmodmap config:

```
# Store default xmodmap 
$ xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap.default 

# Backup your custom xmodmap
$ mv ~/.Xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap.bak

# Make a diff between default and custom xmodmap, and store the diff as .Xmodmap
$ diff ~/.Xmodmap.bak ~/.Xmodmap.default | grep '<' | tr '<' ' ' > ~/.Xmodmap
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on xubuntu 14.04 (64) and xmodmap (with exactly the same keys) and found a solution using xkb instead of xmodmap:
[Remapping Keys in Ubuntu (using xkb)](https://radu.cotescu.com/remapping-keys-in-ubuntu-14.04/)

The xkb solution requires only to change the keycodes in

```
/usr/share/X11/symbols/pc
```

and clear xkb cache by

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

I had no delays afterwards. Maybe this works with Linux Mint as well.

Answer (score 1):

When `xmodmap` runs, it calls `XChangeKeyboardMapping` once for each key it modifies, which generates `MappingNotify` events. In some configurations (mine included), this burst of events causes the system to hang for some time.

I had this problem while creating a customized keyboard map, and my (ugly) workaround was writing a program that generates the C source code that will apply all modifications by calling `XChangeKeyboardMapping` only once, thereby triggering `MappingNotify` only once.

Before running this code, you must apply your map, since it will get the current keyboard mapping.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

int main(void) {
    Display* display;
    int min, max, i, j, k;
    int keysyms_per_keycode;
    KeySym* keysyms;

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XDisplayKeycodes(display, &min, &max);
    keysyms = XGetKeyboardMapping(display, min, max-min, &keysyms_per_keycode);
    printf("#include <stdlib.h>\n");
    printf("#include <stdio.h>\n");
    printf("#include <X11/XKBlib.h>\n\n");
    printf("int main(void) {\n");
    printf("    int first_keycode = %d;\n", min);
    printf("    int keysyms_per_keycode = %d;\n", keysyms_per_keycode);
    printf("    int num_of_keycodes = %d;\n", max-min);
    printf("    KeySym keysyms[%d] = {", ((max-min) * keysyms_per_keycode) + 1);
    for (k = 0, i = 0; i < (max-min); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < keysyms_per_keycode; j++) {
            printf("%ld,", keysyms[k++]);
        }
    }
    printf("0};\n");
    printf("    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);\n");
    printf("    XChangeKeyboardMapping(display,first_keycode,keysyms_per_keycode,keysyms,num_of_keycodes);\n");
    printf("    XCloseDisplay(display);\n");
    printf("    return 0;\n");
    printf("}\n");

    XFree(keysyms);
    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -lX11`.